# Functional form for regression in a hedonic pricing model

Tags: regression, structural-equation-modeling, economics

I am doing a regression where I use the hedonic pricing model. Hedonic pricing treats a marketed good, usually a house, as a sum of individual goods (characteristics or attributes) that cannot be sold separately in the market. The main objective of a hedonic pricing model is to estimate the contribution of such characteristics or attributes to the price of the house.

[image]

In the next step I have written the semi-log functional form/equation which is the following

[image]

I am really bad with equations. Is there anyone that could comment if they see anything wrong with these equations, and if i have to change it? I would really appreciate any comments and feedback.

Comment: This might be a good fit for Economics Stack Exchange where there probably are more experts of hedonic pricing models. So if you do not get a good answer here, you may later try there.

Comment: I see, thank you.